# Awk search pattern with forward slash as complemented bracket expression

Tags: regex, awk

Consider following data:

```
# comments
files-with-relative-paths1
   files-with-relative-paths2
/files-with-absolute-paths1
   /files-with-absolute-paths2
```

I want to match only lines with filenames with relative paths, i.e. no leading `/` (leading whitespace can exist)  using `awk`. I have tried following commands:

```
$ awk '/^\s*[^/]/' testfile.txt
# comments
files-with-relative-paths1
   files-with-relative-paths2
   /files-with-absolute-paths2

$ awk '/^[^#]\s*[^/]/' testfile.txt
files-with-relative-paths1
   files-with-relative-paths2
/files-with-absolute-paths1
   /files-with-absolute-paths2
```

As you can see they do not give the right results

Comment: file names can start with `#` signs so how do you identify a "comment"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't noticed the `!` flag in `awk` which makes it significantly easier:

```
awk '!/(^#)|(^\s*[/])/' testfile.txt
```

The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Usage.html#Regexp-Usage) did not clarify this for the standard pattern.

Comment: Could be written as `'!/^(#|\s*\/)/'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are Ok with using perl:

```
perl -lne 'print unless(/^\s*\//)' your_file
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate other solutions but I am not familiar with perl and if not necessary I stick to awk. And I did also omit that it is actually multi-column data where awk conveniently print the desired column. I should rephrease my question. Originally I was suspecting the problem somewhat related to the double meaning of the forward slash

Answer (score 0):

Assuming none of your file names can start with a `#`:

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /^[^#/]/' file
files-with-relative-paths1
   files-with-relative-paths2
```